# React: Pass component as prop without using this.props.children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have this a component `Foo.js`:

```
// a svg component with a star.svg icon
import { IconStar } from 'react-svg-icons'; 

// call a button with a custom icon
<Button icon={ IconStar }> Click to trigger </Button>
```

And then on `button.js` I have:

```
render() {
  const theIcon = this.props.icon;
  return (
    <button>
      {this.props children}
      {icon() /*this works but i can't pass props inside it*/} 
      <theIcon className={ Styles.buttonIcon } />
    </button>
  )
}
```

I want to render `<IconStar>` inside `<Button>`, how do I do that?.

I can't pass this as `this.prop.children` because it has more logic around the icon prop, but in this case I'm showing only a demo.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The only thing you have missed is that for JSX to transpile to JS custom components should be named starting with a capital letter, e.g. `<TheIcon />`, while lowercase letter signifies native DOM elements, e.g. `<button />`.:

```
render() {
  const TheIcon = this.props.icon;  // note the capital first letter!
  return (
    <button>
      {this.props.children}
      <TheIcon className={ Styles.buttonIcon } />
    </button>
  )
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/03h2swkc/3/

Answer (score 0):

If your using es6 then you can use a spread operator to pass the attributes to a below component, I think that might solve your problem:

```js
var MyIcon = (props) => {
  return <i {...props}> {
    props.className
  } < /i>
};
var MyButton = (props) => {
  return ( < button > {
      props.children
    }<MyIcon {...props} />< /
    button > );
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  MyButton className = 'my-icon'>My Button Text</MyButton> ,
  document.getElementById('myComponent')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='myComponent'></div>
```

so the ...props will pass myProps into IconStar. Obviously you can pass anything you want through.