# react pass a class object as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I know you can pass plain objects and arrays in react props easily.

But my question is if its possible to pass a class object as well?

I mean, I have this class:

```
class Something {
    constructor() {//data}
    method() {...}
    etc...
}
```

now I want to pass that object as a prop:

```
let sm1 = new Something();
<Component item={sm1} />
```

if you wonder why is simply because I have a big array of specific rules that I easily use the rules inside that class.

Comment: Why not???, Everything is an object in javascript. did you give it a try.

Comment: There is no difference between class object and plain object.

Comment: Maybe I'm scared as I need to be functional like in redux...

Comment: hope this help,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42510874/react-pass-component-as-prop-without-using-this-props-children

Answer (score 5):

A `class` is an `object` in JavaScript and it makes no difference if you pass a class, an object or an array. You can pass the class instance without having any side-effects. Its just like a passing a function as a prop

```
let sm1 = new Something();
<Component item={sm1} />
```

would be similar to

```
<Component handleChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Comment: What about rendering? Can react detect changes in the class internals even though the instance is the same?

Comment: I just came across that pitfall. If you use `Memo` to wrap your component, and you just update a property of an instance of a class, React will not redner. Because it is essentially the same insance. I have to overwrite `propsAreEqual` to compare the differences.